# How to get live changes from TextField

Tags: ios, swift, events, delegates, uitextfield

I am getting values from TextField using tags and an IB method action. I can get values when after editing I click on the body of the tableview.

```
cell.component.tag = indexPath.row

cell.component.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTextViewOther(_:)), for: .editingDidEnd)
```

Then I have my objc method

```
 @objc func handleTextViewOther(_ sender: UITextField){

        let indexPath : IndexPath = IndexPath(item: sender.tag, section: 0)

        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! OnlyTextCell
        if let key = cell.displayLabel.text, let val = cell.component.text{
            print ("sender \(key) Field value = \(val)")
        }
    }
```

**Works as expected:** After typing stuff on the textfield, if I press outside, I get the correct value

**Doesn't work:** If I keep editing and my focus is on the textfield, and if I click the 'Submit' button, I don't get the latest text. In the 'for' part, I have tried multiple combinations of 'all touch events' to 'didEndEditing', but no luck

I have researched and I think I need `textDidChangeNotification`

But within the  `#selector(handleTextViewOther(_:)), for: .editingDidEnd` for: doesn't consist of the thing that I am looking for. How to please?

Or is there any other things I can do?

Comment: Is `textFieldEditingDidChange` what you are looking for?

Comment: probably, but this options does not come up on the 'for:'
```Type 'UIControl.Event' has no member 'textFieldEditingDidChange' ```

Answer (score 1):

`for: .editingChanged`

Silly me, this solved it!